# how to add "Rate The App" link in Google Play store app (jetpack compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a button that I want it to send me to the Play Store to rate the app. couldn't find any about jetpack compose

Comment: Its no different in Compose ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call this method inside the [onClick of your button](https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-button/).

```
fun openPlayStore(activityContext: Context, appURL: String) {
    val playIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {

        action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW

        data = Uri.parse(appURL)

    }
    try {
        activityContext.startActivity(playIntent)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // handle the exception
    }
}
```

You should pass activity context (not application context).

Answer (score 1):

##### Set up your development environment

The Play In-App Review Library is a part of the Google Play Core libraries. Please include the following Gradle dependency to integrate the Play In-App Review Library.

```
// In your app’s build.gradle file:
...
dependencies {
    // This dependency is downloaded from the Google’s Maven repository.
    // So, make sure you also include that repository in your project's build.gradle file.
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0'

    // For Kotlin users also add the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Review:
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.0'
    ...
}
```

##### Create the ReviewManager and Request a ReviewInfo object

The `ReviewManager` is the interface that lets your app start an in-app review flow. Obtain it by creating an instance using the `ReviewManagerFactory`.

Follow the guidance about when to request in-app reviews to determine good points in your app's user flow to prompt the user for a review (for example, when the user completes a level in a game). When your app reaches one of these points, use the `ReviewManager` instance to create a request task. If successful, the API returns the `ReviewInfo` object needed to start the in-app review flow.

```
val manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(requireActivity())
// val manager = FakeReviewManager(requireActivity())
val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
      if (task.isSuccessful) {
           val reviewInfo = task.result
           val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(requireActivity(), reviewInfo)
           flow.addOnCompleteListener {}
      } else {
           Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
}
```

Comment: do i have to make a requireActivity()? because it doesnt show up for me

Comment: It is the "context", you need to pass. @MoonSculptor